# sweetalert2-react onCancel not called

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert2

I set showCancelButton and onCancel, when I click the cancel button, instead of the onCancel callback function, the onConfirm is called instead. So both the confirm and cancel buttons call the same function.

This is for a react app initialized using create-react-app, dependency on sweetalert2-react version "^0.8.1"

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SweetAlert from "sweetalert2-react";
class Test extends Component {
    state = {};
    render() {
        return (
            <SweetAlert
                show={true}
                showCancelButton={true}
                onConfirm={() => alert("confirm")}
                onCancel={() => alert("cancel")}
                text="Test"
            />
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

I always get alert "confirm", and never "cancel", clicking either button

Comment: Can you try to control `show` props with `state` ?

Comment: Yup that's what I did in my code, same results. This is just hardcoded for demonstration purposes